# Installation of gym on Mac issue

Tags: python, macos, numpy, openai-gym

When I am running a command

```
pip install gym
```

I am getting error as :

```
"ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall."
```

Kindly help in resolving the issue to install gym on mac

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Your `pip` is maybe from your system/OS python 2.7. Don't use that. Use a python3 installation, create a virtual env, and install gym inside there using `python3 -m pip install <package>`

Comment: @GinoMempin : error is same even in venv

Comment: @yudhiesh : 2.7 and 3.9

Comment: Could you try `pip3 install gym`?

Comment: tried already but error